# Ошибка при выкладывании приложения в App store на моменте архивирования из Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

я написал свое приложение для ios(apple Iphone) и собрался выкладывать но тут у меня появилась проблема. Я зарегестрировал приложение на сайте Apple Developer, сделал сертификат, добавил устройство, сделал профиль и вроде на сайте все сделал, затем перешел на App store Connect и там тоже зарегистрировал, ввел название и описание и тд, и теперь осталась последняя часть - сборка приложение, ну я перешел в Xcode нажал "Archive" все получилось и нажал distribute app все подтвердил началась загрузка, и через секунд 5 загрузка заканчивается и выдаются ошибки :

[image: На фото сами ошибки]

пробовал и с другими приложениями, что я только не перепробовал, все те же ошибки, помогите пожалуйста решить проблему, никак не пойму в чем дело..

P.S
Даже пробовал через приложение "Transporter" и там те же ошибки не понимаю с чем это может быть связанно..

P.S
В программе ошибок нет и желтых меток тоже все иконки загружены, замечаний 0

Comment: Нет коннекта, что-то у вас с vpn или прокси, смотрите настройки сети.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка была в прокси в настройках:
чтобы все заработало надо пройти путь - Настройки->сеть->дополнительно->прокси
поставить галочку на автообнаружение прокси сервера и автоконфигурация прокси и убрать галочки у всех остальных

Comment: Пожалуйста, пометьте вам вопрос как решённый и не забудьте поставить оценки всем тем, кто вам помог в решении этой проблемы